# Moving CSS boxes to center in webpage once browser size is big enough?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I've noticed on many websites from Facebook to stackoverflow that most elements have a fixed hight and width and are placed at a certain distance from the left border of the page. However, once the page is stretched, all the elements move together towards a more central position within the webpage. How could this be executed in Html and CSS with just a couple of box elements?

any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a precise example with an image and maybe your HTML markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set a max-width to the container and apply margin:0 auto; to it, and it will automatically behave as such.

http://jsfiddle.net/ast53pu7/

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="center">This will center</div>
</div>


.container{
    width:100%;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:100px 0;
}

#center{
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    max-width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This is responsive web design.

Answer (score 0):

They use CSS media queries  probably

Answer (score 0):

That is something called "responsive web design" or shorter "rwd".